# Upload file using curl to an URL known in advance

Tags: curl, file-upload

I hope this question is for stack-overflow. If not please tell me where is a better place to ask it.

I'm looking for a free file upload service, like [transfer.sh](https://transfer.sh/) or [file.io](https://www.file.io/) where I can upload files from a script using curl but upload to an URL known in advance.

When using transfer.sh or file.io you get a URL with some randomly generated string like: https://transfer.sh/eibhM/hello.txt (eibhM is the randomly generated string in this example).

I'm looking for a free service when I can upload a file using curl to a certain "folder" of my own like: https://some-upload-service.com/fx23/hello.txt

If someone knows such a service it'd be a great help